# Blurry Adorner WPF Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blurry

I cannot for the life of me figure this out, using the same control template I get a blurry Adorner on one Element in my panel:

[image]

Control Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationErrorTemplateBubble" >
<DockPanel >
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Direction="315" />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,-1.6,0,0">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE7E8F1" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F4F6" Offset="0.472"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>

            <Grid>
                <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,10,5">
                    <Image Source="/Sesam;component/Modules/Images/wrongsmall.png" Height="15" Width="15" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="12" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
                </WrapPanel>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Path Data="M306.375,133.125L306.375,100.875L335.75,133.25" Stroke="Gray" Height="15" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Uniform"  Margin="10,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" />
</DockPanel>
```

Non-Blury Text Box Code:

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Padding="3" Margin="8,0,0,0" Foreground="{StaticResource myDarkBlue}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.encTypeValidation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplateBubble}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.editClicked}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

Blurry TextBox Code:

```
    <Grid>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbox" Text="{Binding encTypeValidation, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Foreground="{StaticResource myTextBoxColor}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplateBubble}" PreviewMouseDown="tbox_PreviewMouseDown" Width="200" >
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding addBoxClicked}" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Something about the way it renders, the first (non blury) is within a "ListViewItem" Control Template, the other is a userControl..

Any ideas?

***FIXED***

Fixed by adding UseLayoutRounding="True" to parent Control ie: ContentControl!

Thank you Aybe!

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="{StaticResource myLightGrey}" >
        <Border  BorderBrush="{StaticResource myLightGrey}" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0">
            <ContentControl x:Name="AddPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Try UseLayoutRounding and SnapToDevicePixels.

Comment: Bumping your rep so that you can do inline screenshots in the future. Good luck.

Comment: @Aybe tried SnapToDevicePixels on almost all the elements before posting, thinking it has something to do with that, will try UseLayoutRounding (though I think i tried) which element would you apply it to? In the Adorner ControleTemplate I suppose..

Comment: @Bobby, thank you! It was frustrating not being able too hehe :)

Comment: @Aybe thank you! I added UseLayoutRounding to parent control ie: ContentControl and it renders perfectly, tyvm :)

Comment: cool, fixed your pics as well.

Comment: Aybe, you should post this solution as an answer.

Comment: Aww you too kind thanks m8 :) Added result aswell, yes please post solution as answer I will validate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding UseLayoutRounding="True" to the parent container control solves the rendering issue.